# Why did my question get deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I checked my reputation history recently and discovered that my question, [Convert JSON strings to normalized schema in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833569/convert-json-strings-to-normalized-schema-in-sql-server) was deleted.

I think the question was decent, even though it never got an answer. How can I find out why it was deleted?

I do not think this is a duplicate, because the other question starts with knowing the deletion reason. This question is just asking for the deletion reason.

Comment: If you can find a previous instance of where you got or lost rep from that post in your reputation history, that will have a link to the post, just as a tip. :) Though if it was deleted by the system for being untouched and unanswered for so long, that'll be a heck of a search, I'm sure.

Comment: Found it from [cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833569/convert-json-strings-to-normalized-schema-in-sql-server) (it was a RemoveAbandonedQuestion).

Comment: @pnuts I got a -3 (which is still there) and the text "removed        Convert JSON strings to normalized schema in SQL Server"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833569/convert-json-strings-to-normalized-schema-in-sql-server). I undeleted it for the sake of discussion, and because it didn't seem too bad to me.

It was [automatically deleted by the system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) because it met the criteria:

> If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...
>
> - has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in
>     days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
> - isn't on a meta site
>
> ... it will be
>   automatically deleted. These are termed "abandoned" questions
>   (RemoveAbandonedQuestions).

Comment: That explains it. It might be useful to have a link to that page on the reputation history timeline when the remove occurs, so it seems less mysterious.